# PHP 7.0 Cron job error

Tags: php

I updated php 5.6 to php 7.0 and now on my mail box i got cron job error.

This is subject of my mail:

[ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && /usr/lib/php/sessionclean

This is whole mail i get:

google docs: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1f-e4l0CmeoWRX29o8EFlJTzS2qOFsiw0_B45pj33-9k/edit?usp=sharing

Please help me!

here is first 30 lines of mail i get... Whole mail got 1532 lines...

```
From root@serwer  Wed Jul  6 21:39:03 2016
Return-Path: <root@serwer>
Received: from serwer (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by serwer (8.14.4/8.14.4/Debian-8) with ESMTP id u66Jd2mV025696
    for <root@serwer>; Wed, 6 Jul 2016 21:39:02 +0200
Received: (from root@localhost)
    by serwer (8.14.4/8.14.4/Submit) id u66Jd2IT025695
    for root; Wed, 6 Jul 2016 21:39:02 +0200
Date: Wed, 6 Jul 2016 21:39:02 +0200
Message-Id: <201607061939.u66Jd2IT025695@serwer>
From: root@serwer (Cron Daemon)
To: root@serwer
Subject: Cron <root@serwer>   [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && /usr/lib/php/sessionclean
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/root>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=root>

PHP Warning:  Module 'mysqlnd' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mysqli' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
MIB search path: /root/.snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/iana:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/ietf:/usr/share/mibs/site:/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/usr/share/mibs/iana:/usr/share/mibs/ietf:/usr/share/mibs/netsnmp
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TC): At line 10 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-DLMOD-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-SMI): At line 34 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TC): At line 37 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt
Did not find 'enterprises' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'DisplayString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'TruthValue' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/UCD-SNMP-MIB.txt)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the error message no one wants to download an unknown file, and external links are subject to link rot.

Comment: There is to many errors so i paste it to google docs...https://docs.google.com/document/d/1f-e4l0CmeoWRX29o8EFlJTzS2qOFsiw0_B45pj33-9k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Why can't you paste it into your question instead of a third party service, why make those who can help do extra work you should do?

Comment: I write this again, i cant paste it because text is to long... You realy think i paste hacks on google docs? Is it even possible?

Comment: No I think using google makes the info subject to link rot, and more work for those of us who can help.Yes, you can exploit google docs.